# Sorting multiple NSMutableArrays

Tags: cocoa, collections

I have high scores (name, score, time) stored in a single file and I divide them into separate arrays once it reads them, only problem is I can't figure out a way to sort all three by score and time from least to greatest and still keep the correct order of values.
For example:

```
Name score time
---------------
nathan 123 01:12
bob    321 55:32
frank  222 44:44
```

turns to:

```
bob    123 01:12
frank  222 44:44
nathan 321 55:32
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encapsulate the data into a single object (`HighScore`) that has three properties: `name`, `time`, and `score`.  Then store them in a single array and sort the single array.

Welcome to object-oriented programming.

Comment: how would i do that, by creating an abject?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create a new class.

Comment: how would i sort them after creating an object?

Comment: Using the sorting methods on `NSArray`.... http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW12 and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547

Comment: nathanjosiah: You'll need to implement the `compare:` method in the model object.

Comment: how would i do that, i am very new to sorting arrays, i am not semi new to objective c

Comment: @Peter - not necessarily.  He can use an `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the array.  That'll use the `compare:` methods already implemented on `NSDate`, `NSString`, etc.  Implementing `compare:` is really only necessary if you need to do non-simple comparison (ie, compare multiple properties at once).